# Setup a UITextView's size and alignment

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble setting up my UITextView that will contain a single digit.  I want the view to be small and the text to be in the center both horizontally and vertically.

Instantiate the view:

```
let setNumberView: UITextView = {
        let view = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: heightForView(text: "8", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), width: 25), height: heightForView(text: "8", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), width: 25)))
        view.text = "1"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        print("FONT SIZE: \(view.font?.pointSize)")
        return view
    }()
```

Setup the constraints:

```
/* setNumberView */

        let setDiameter = heightForView(text: "8", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), width: 25)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-4-[v0]", views: setNumberView)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: setNumberView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        //height
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: setNumberView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: setDiameter))
        //width
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: setNumberView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: setDiameter))
```

But I am left with this:

[image]

My goal is to have the "1" in the white box centered horizontally and vertically.

Here is how I am getting the height/width:

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
}
```

Comment: why use a uilabel to size a textview?  why not disable scrolling on the uitextview to make it use its intrinsic size?

Comment: It's a function I use for several things.  But idk, I mm a beginner who is open to suggestions

Comment: turn off the scrolling enabled and a textview will size itself like a uilabel. you could make a height function to calculate it or you could use autolayout and automatic dimensions.

Comment: only other thing about a uitextview is you may need to remote the insets

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```